# Query on a JS callback function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have little question about function in JS: once the RadConfirm pops up with the message and I click on the cancel button, I want to stay on same page and check the checkbox that I have. Instead the RadConfim box pops up again and then need to click on the cancel button all over again.

```
function deactivateAccountChecked(sender, eventArgs) {
    radconfirm('Are you sure you want to disable this account?</br>If you continue, the user will not be able to use the system.</br></br>Only Case Global will be able to re-active this account.', confirmDisableCallBackFn, 370, 225, null, 'Case Global Deactivate Account');           
}

function confirmDisableCallBackFn(arg) {
    var check = $find("<%=activeAccount.ClientID %>");
    if (arg == false) {
        check.set_checked(true); 
    }
    else {
        check.set_checked(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `radConfirm`?

Comment: Could you also show how `deactivateAccountChecked` is called? (oh and for the heck of it  after call to `radconfirm` try adding `return false;`